# Why is this object null?

Tags: java, object, null

Im fairly new to Java and I am getting an "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Both textfields are coming back as null and Im not sure why as I used .setText() and it shows up in the textfield

Essentially what I am trying to do is pass the value in velocityTextView and pass it to
returnTextView.

I tried `returnTextView.setText(velocityTextView.getText());`
I put this code in the `actionPerformed()` method.

Im stuck and I would love some guidance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class kinematica implements ActionListener {

    public JPanel totalGui;
    public JLabel progTitle;
    public JButton enterBtn;
    public JTextField velocityTextField, returnTextField;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        showGui();

    }

    public JPanel createContentPane() {

        //  GUI panel to contain the elements that make GUI
        JPanel totalGui = new JPanel();
        totalGui.setLayout(null);


        // Title Label 
        JLabel progTitle = new JLabel("Linear Motion 1D");
        progTitle.setLocation(10, 10);
        progTitle.setSize(500, 30);
        progTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        totalGui.add(progTitle);



        // Buttons
        JButton enterBtn = new JButton("Enter");
        enterBtn.setLocation(100, 200);
        enterBtn.setSize(100, 50);
        enterBtn.addActionListener(this);
        totalGui.add(enterBtn);


        // text fields
        JTextField velocityTextField = new JTextField(20);
        velocityTextField.setLocation(100, 50);
        velocityTextField.setSize(80, 30);
        velocityTextField.setText("Velocity =");
        totalGui.add(velocityTextField);

        JTextField returnTextField = new JTextField();
        returnTextField.setLocation(100, 100);
        returnTextField.setSize(80, 30);
        returnTextField.setText("test1");
        totalGui.add(returnTextField);


        totalGui.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGui;

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        returnTextField.getText();

        System.out.println(velocityTextField);

    }

    public static void showGui() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Kinematica");
        kinematica demoWindow = new kinematica();
        window.setContentPane(demoWindow.createContentPane());

        window.setSize(1500, 1000);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all the class names from `createContentPane` function.

When you say `JLabel progTitle`, you are creating a **local variable to the function**, and thus are NOT talking about the member variable. This creates the situation of [Variable Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), thanks MadProgrammer, which causes your problem.

Thus when you later access the member variable, it is untouched, and hence `null`.

Change

```
JTextField returnTextField = new JTextField();
```

to

```
returnTextField = new JTextField();
```

in this and similar lines in that function.

Comment: That worked brilliantly thanks!  I see what went wrong now.  new to java, good learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are shadowing your variables.  You declare the two `JTextField's as instance fields

```
public JTextField velocityTextField, returnTextField;

public JPanel createContentPane() {
    /*...*/

    // text fields
    JTextField velocityTextField = new JTextField(20);
    /*...*/

    JTextField returnTextField = new JTextField();
```

Then, redeclare them in your `createContentPane` method

Instead, remove the local declarations, for example...

```
public JTextField velocityTextField, returnTextField;

public JPanel createContentPane() {
    /*...*/

    // text fields
    velocityTextField = new JTextField(20);
    /*...*/

    returnTextField = new JTextField();
```

Comment: @karthikt Feel free to add it to your answer

Comment: I did, abt 2 seconds after the +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

As Karthik said:

remove the class names from `createContentPane`.  What this would look like is:

```
public JPanel createContentPane() {

    //  GUI panel to contain the elements that make GUI
    totalGui = new JPanel();
    totalGui.setLayout(null);


    // Title Label 
    progTitle = new JLabel("Linear Motion 1D");
    progTitle.setLocation(10, 10);
    progTitle.setSize(500, 30);
    progTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    totalGui.add(progTitle);



    // Buttons
    enterBtn = new JButton("Enter");
    enterBtn.setLocation(100, 200);
    enterBtn.setSize(100, 50);
    enterBtn.addActionListener(this);
    totalGui.add(enterBtn);


    // text fields
    velocityTextField = new JTextField(20);
    velocityTextField.setLocation(100, 50);
    velocityTextField.setSize(80, 30);
    velocityTextField.setText("Velocity =");
    totalGui.add(velocityTextField);

    returnTextField = new JTextField();
    returnTextField.setLocation(100, 100);
    returnTextField.setSize(80, 30);
    returnTextField.setText("test1");
    totalGui.add(returnTextField);


    totalGui.setOpaque(true);
    return totalGui;

}
```

Why do this?  Because you are declaring LOCAL variables when you put the class name in front of the variable name in your method.  Instead, you want to use the public fields you've declared.  To avoid running into this problem again I recommend the convention of underscores for instance variables and no underscores for local.  So you could use `_enterBtn` instead of `enterBtn` to check yourself in the future.

Comment: I definitely see thats what happened.  and I will for sure using the underscore from now on.